# If $N$ is semisimple and and $M/N$ semisimple then $M$ semisimple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, representation-theory, algebras

Let $R$ be finite dimensional $k$ algebra, $k$ is a field possibly $\mathbb{C}$. Let $_RN\leq{}_RM$ (submodule as  a left module). Is the following statement true (if yes could you give me a hint) , if $_RN$ is semisimple and $_RM/N$ semisimple then $_RM$ semisimple?

Comment: I don't think so, as such a result, if true, would be in any book on the subject. I couldn't find it in Bourbaki, Algebra, Ch. 8, *Semi-simple Modules and Rings*.

Comment: What is your definition of semi-simple?  I would define a module to be semi-simple if it is the sum of its simple submodules, in which case the statement you've made is true.

Comment: @Jim yes this is  the way I have been taught about semisimple modules. Could you explain your yes  please?

Comment: Whoops, brainfart.  I was wrong, I'll post an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, for example let $k$ be any field you like and consider the ring $R = k[x]/x^2$.

The ideal $(x) \leq R$ is one dimensional and the quotient $R/(x)$ is one dimensional so both of these are simple (hence semisimple) $R$-modules.  But the ring $R$ is not semisimple as a module over itself because the ideal $(x)$ is the only simple submodule of $R$.

If the ring $R$ that you're working with is a semisimple ring (i.e. semisimple as a module over itself) then the statement becomes true.

Comment: That is nice, thank you. But I wonder what prevents that from being correct, by this I mean  I would like to know the sufficient condition for this statement to hold.

Comment: What prevents it is that the ring itself is not semisimple.

Comment: The statement you've made holds for all finitely generated $R$-modules if and only $R$ is a semisimple ring.

Comment: Dear @Jim, by $k[x]/x^2$ you meant $k[x]/(x^2)$?

Comment: @rgm, Yep, those are the same to me.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
The idea is that finite dimensional ( over $k$) $R$ modules $M$ have finite length, that is,
there exists a sequence of submodules 
$$0=M_0 \subset M_1 \subset \ldots \subset M_n = M$$
that can not be refined any further, that is, $M_{l-1}$ is maximal inside $M_l$, in other words, $M_{l}/M_{l-1}$ is simple. So any module is a composition of simple modules (and so, of semisimple modules). But if $R$ itself is not semisimple, there are some non-semisimple modules $M$ out there ( for instance, $R$ itself)

No.